# Get sub URLs from main URL

Tags: python, url, web

I'm unsure how to properly phrase this question, so please be kind and let me know how to properly ask this :)

Say I have a URL: www.potato.com

How can I find all the working sub URLs from this domain? eg, the ones in bold:

www.potato.com/hidden_pages/**you_cannot_guess_this_page**

www.potato.com/hidden_pages/**cant_guess_this_either**

Is there a way i can query www.potato.com/hidden_pages/ to get all the sub URLs?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

If the websever has directory listing enabled (e.g. see how to do it in [nginx](http://nginxlibrary.com/enable-directory-listing/) or [apache](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings)), then you can query the directory `www.potato.com/hidden_pages` and you'll get back a list of files/directories under it which can be parsed with something like [beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Alternately, if the website has a sitemap ( e.g. www.potato.com/sitemap.xml ), you can parse that to figure out the pages under 'hidden_pages' provided that it's been listed in sitemap.

TL:DR : If the webmaster wants you to be able to access these pages, then you can do it with the above methods, else you have to brute force / guess the links.